# Can printing be inhibited in PyCharm unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I have this test that passes. But it also prints two lines to the console, which makes it cluttered. How can that be inhibited?

Not using PyCharm, I would set sys.stdout = io.StringIO.StringIO(), in the setUp method, but that doesn't work in PyCharm. PyCharm seems to pick up values from StringIO() and print they anyway.

```py
class Tests_with_print(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def tearDown(self):
        pass
    def testThatPrintoutsCanBeTested(self):
        print("some text", file=sys.stdout)
        self.assertIn("some text", sys.stdout.getvalue())
        print("some error", file=sys.stderr)
        self.assertIn("some error", sys.stderr.getvalue())
```

Comment: Using logging level to control the message you want to show could be a nice way. Sometimes you just don't want them all but need some logs to debug.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. This is intended to be a unit test of a function that prints something. To keep the example simple, I'm testing the print function itself. Print is my method under test. In the unit testing environment, I don't want print to actually print in a visible way. I only want it to be testable.

Comment: I totally understand your purpose. What I mean is you can replace the print functions in your tests with python logging function. Say your logging level in the unit testing environment is default (logging.INFO) and the logging level inside your unit tests are logging.DEBUG, which is more verbose. The logger will mute so you don't see any print. You can easily control the logging level with an environment variable defined by yourself.